# Split a value into two columns based on time of day in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

The energy usage of a device is logged hourly:

```
+--------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| energy_usage | device_id |  timestamp            |
+--------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| 10           | 1         |  2019-02-12T01:00:00  |
| 16           | 2         |  2019-02-12T01:00:00  |
| 26           | 1         |  2019-03-12T02:00:00  |
| 24           | 2         |  2019-03-12T02:00:00  |
+--------------+-----------+-----------------------+
```

My goal is:

1. Create two columns, one for `energy_usage_day` (8am-8pm) and another for `energy_usage_night` (8pm-8am)
2. Create a monthly aggregate, group by device_id and sum up the energy usage
3. Remove rows with a monthly energy usage lower 50

So the result might look like this:

```
+--------------+------------------+--------------------+-----------+---------+------+
| energy_usage | energy_usage_day | energy_usage_night | device_id |  month  | year |
+--------------+------------------+--------------------+-----------+---------+------+
| 80           | 30               | 50                 | 1         | 2       | 2019 |
| 130          | 60               | 70                 | 2         | 3       | 2019 |
+--------------+------------------+--------------------+-----------+---------+------+
```

In step 2 I would use

```
SUM(energy_usage) OVER (PARTITION BY device_id ORDER BY FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%m", TIMESTAMP(timestamp)))
```

However I am not sure how to accomplish step 1. Is it even possible in bigquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IF`, no need to use `OVER`:

```
SELECT SUM(energy_usage) energy_usage
  , SUM(IF(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM timestamp) BETWEEN 8 AND 19, energy_usage, 0)) energy_usage_day
  , SUM(IF(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM timestamp) NOT BETWEEN 8 AND 19, energy_usage, 0)) energy_usage_night
  , device_id
  , EXTRACT(MONTH FROM timestamp) month, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM timestamp) year
FROM `data`
GROUP BY device_id, month, year
```

Comment: Also, you can add `HAVING energy_usage >= 50` to the end to satisfy step #3