# Start SUM aggregation at a certain threshold in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

The energy usage of a device is logged hourly:

```
+--------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| energy_usage | device_id |  timestamp            |
+--------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| 10           | 1         |  2019-02-12T01:00:00  |
| 16           | 2         |  2019-02-12T01:00:00  |
| 26           | 1         |  2019-03-12T02:00:00  |
| 24           | 2         |  2019-03-12T02:00:00  |
+--------------+-----------+-----------------------+
```

My goal is:

1. Create two columns, one for `energy_usage_day` (8am-8pm) and another for `energy_usage_night` (8pm-8am)
2. Create a monthly aggregate, group by device_id and sum up the energy usage

So the result might look like this:

```
+--------------+------------------+--------------------+-----------+---------+------+
| energy_usage | energy_usage_day | energy_usage_night | device_id |  month  | year |
+--------------+------------------+--------------------+-----------+---------+------+
| 80           | 30               | 50                 | 1         | 2       | 2019 |
| 130          | 60               | 70                 | 2         | 3       | 2019 |
+--------------+------------------+--------------------+-----------+---------+------+
```

Following query produces such results:

```
SELECT SUM(energy_usage) energy_usage
  , SUM(IF(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM timestamp) BETWEEN 8 AND 19, energy_usage, 0)) energy_usage_day
  , SUM(IF(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM timestamp) NOT BETWEEN 8 AND 19, energy_usage, 0)) energy_usage_night
  , device_id
  , EXTRACT(MONTH FROM timestamp) month, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM timestamp) year
FROM `data`
GROUP BY device_id, month, year
```

Say I am only interested in energy usage aggregates above a certain threshold, e.g. 50. I want to start the SUM at a total energy usage of 50. The result should look like this:

```
+--------------+------------------+--------------------+-----------+---------+------+
| energy_usage | energy_usage_day | energy_usage_night | device_id |  month  | year |
+--------------+------------------+--------------------+-----------+---------+------+
| 30           | 10               | 20                 | 1         | 2       | 2019 |
| 80           | 50               | 30                 | 2         | 3       | 2019 |
+--------------+------------------+--------------------+-----------+---------+------+
```

In other words: the query should start summing up energy_usage, energy_usage_day and energy_usage_night only when energy_usage reaches the threshold of 50.

Is this possible in bigquery?

Comment: What logic do you want to use to filter out that 50 energy? Do you want to ignore the first 50 energy used on each day?

Comment: @EricKeen I want to ignore the first 50 used in a month.

Comment: Using your data I can't get the output as posted in your question since when you group by month and device you get 4 rows and not 2. Anyway I took some assumption and posted an answer per my understanding of your need

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split a value into two columns based on time of day in bigquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55847506/split-a-value-into-two-columns-based-on-time-of-day-in-bigquery)

Comment: @PolOrtiz no it is not. I created the question the linked. This is a followup question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and logic is that it starts aggregate usage ONLY after it reaches 50 (per device per month)

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH temp AS (
  SELECT *, SUM(energy_usage) OVER(win) > 50 qualified,
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM `timestamp`) BETWEEN 8 AND 20 day_hour,
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM `timestamp`) month, 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM `timestamp`) year    
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY device_id, TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(`timestamp`, MONTH) ORDER BY `timestamp`)
)
SELECT SUM(energy_usage) energy_usage,
  SUM(IF(day_hour, energy_usage, 0)) energy_usage_day,
  SUM(IF(NOT day_hour, energy_usage, 0)) energy_usage_night,
  device_id,
  month, 
  year
FROM temp
WHERE qualified
GROUP BY device_id, month, year
```

> Say the current SUM of usage is 49 and the next usage entry has a value of 2. The SUM will be 51. As a result usage of 2 will be added to the SUM. Instead only half of 1 should've been added. Can we solve such problem in BigQuery SQL?

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH temp AS (
  SELECT *, SUM(energy_usage) OVER(win) > 50 qualified,
    SUM(energy_usage) OVER(win) - 50 rolling_sum,
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM `timestamp`) BETWEEN 8 AND 20 day_hour,
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM `timestamp`) month, 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM `timestamp`) year    
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY device_id, TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(`timestamp`, MONTH) ORDER BY `timestamp`)
), temp_with_adjustments AS (
  SELECT *, 
    IF(
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY device_id, month, year ORDER BY `timestamp`) = 1, 
      rolling_sum, 
      energy_usage
    ) AS adjusted_energy_usage
  FROM temp 
  WHERE qualified
)
SELECT SUM(adjusted_energy_usage) energy_usage,
  SUM(IF(day_hour, adjusted_energy_usage, 0)) energy_usage_day,
  SUM(IF(NOT day_hour, adjusted_energy_usage, 0)) energy_usage_night,
  device_id,
  month, 
  year
FROM temp_with_adjustments
GROUP BY device_id, month, year
```

As you can see, I've just added logic for `temp_with_adjustments` (and rolling_sum in the `temp` to support this) - the rest is the same

Comment: Thank you Mikhail! Say the current SUM of usage is 49 and the next usage entry has a value of 2. The SUM will be 51. As a result usage of 2 will be added to the SUM. Instead only half of 1 should've beed added. Can we solve such problem in BigQuery SQL? Or might Google Dataflow be the way to go?

Comment: Should be doable adjustment. will check latter in a day and will update my answer then

Comment: sorry, didn't have chance yesterday to look into this  - will try today

Comment: see update. I think it addresses your request for partial addition in split hour

Comment: Works as expected!:) Thank you Mikhail!

Comment: Hey Mikhail! I have a follow up question. I am trying to modify your query to return rows grouped by date instead of just month and year. So I replaced the extract statements and TIMESTAMP_TRUNC with ``DATE(TIMESTAMP(timestamp)) as date`` and further replaced every occurrence of month, year with date. However that query is not returning any results. Any ideas why? The modified query: https://pastebin.com/raw/iyQR22xc